# How to create shadow effect on UIImage bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uibezierpath

I have a `UIImageView` in which I have a `UIImage` obviously. I want to create a shadow effect only on the `UIImage`. My problem is that I cannot get the `CGRect` of the `UIImage` inside the `UIImageView` so I can apply the shadow effect on it by using the following method.

```
[mImageView.layer.shadowColor   = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
mImageView.layer.shadowOffset  = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
mImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9f;
mImageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
CGRect imageFrame = mImageView.frame;

UIEdgeInsets shadowInsets     = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -1.5f, 0);
UIBezierPath *shadowPath      = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(imageFrame, shadowInsets)];
mImageView.layer.shadowPath    = shadowPath.CGPath;
```

Please consider the image attached for this problem.
The problem is critical too because the `UIImage` can be an image of a rigid dimension because it is a cropped image as you can see in the picture attached.

The `UIImageView’s` bound is equal to the view’s bound here. So when applying the effect using the method above, it creates a `UIBezierPath` on the whole `UIImageView`, not only to the `UIImage`. As in the method, I cannot get the exact `CGRect` of the `UIImage`.

Any solution? What am I missing?

[cropped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuQhf.jpg)

Comment: why I am getting minus points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImage is always rectangular, so is UIImageView. I believe you want to put shadow only around the jagged border of the cropped area right? If that is the case, you cannot use this method. You need to use CoreGraphics or others, to get the effect you want. For example, you can create a copy of this image in memory, blackened it, and blur it and paste it behind your image to create a shadowy effect.